# The same Minterm Twice in a sequental D flip flop

Tags: flipflop, sequential-logic

So my professor gave me a question that I have to search the answer for, it's a sequential D flip flop circuit with this sequence.
[image]

I have searched far and wide and still don't understand how to solve 2 minterms but reversed to one another...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about homework, with no effort to solve it, and lacks a question.

Comment: not about homework tho he was giving me a challenge and I did try :) using the usual Kmap which my professor only teaches me it just doesn't make sense..

Comment: a keyword for the problem is greatly appreciated, no need for the full answer :)

Comment: Can you draw a state diagram? That would be a good first step.

Comment: Hint: you're going to need a fifth FF.